Properties Uniquely Determining the Kernel Subgroup of a Jacobi Symbol Homomorphism
It's a known proposition that for
$0 \neq D \equiv 0, 1 \text{mod }4$, there is a unique homomorphism $\chi : (\mathbb{Z} / D) \to \{{±1}\}$ such that $\chi([p]) = (D/p)$ for odd primes $p \nmid D$, where $\left( \frac{.}{n}\right)$ denotes the Jacobi symbol, which allows ker$(\chi)$ to be uniquely determined by some four properties. Note that $\chi([-1])$ is $1$ when $D > 0$, and $-1$ when $D < 0$.
I would like to prove that when $D = 4q$, for  an odd prime $q$, only the following properties are needed to determine ker$(\chi)$ uniquely.
i) $ker(\chi)$ is an index 2 subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/D)^{*}$ (the group of invertible elements)
ii) $-1 \in ker(\chi)$ for $q > 0$, and $-1 \notin ker(\chi)$ for $q < 0$.
My intuition was to try use facts about index $2$ subgroups in the finitely generated abelian groups that $(\mathbb{Z}/D)^*$ give rise to, like $(\mathbb{Z}/D)^* \cong \mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/(p - 1)$, but I'm quite unfamiliar with this kind of question so I'm not sure how I'd go about a proof. It's easy to show that the kernel here has $p-1$ elements, and there's a split between two cosets, but I'm unable to make proper use of anything.
Presumably, we're either to construct ker$(\chi)$ using these two properties, or let $G$ be an arbitrary subgroup satisfying i), ii) and show it's the same set as ker$(\chi)$.
